# Firease Crashlytics positioned native crash method not match real crash method

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I use this laibraries

```
//api 'com.mobile.plugins.base.dev:xxx:xxx       //contains my native so libraries
//implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0"))  
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk'
//implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
//plugins  
//classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15"
//classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.9.6'
and execute ./gradlew app:uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease
```

after crashed i saw this
I do not now is symboleupload error , if so  how to upload symbol
i want to konw how to upload symbol when my project cotains third liabrary which include so liabrariees

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.